# How to install a wall-safe in a concrete wall?

Tags: concrete, installation

Our walls are made of poured concrete.

If I wanted to install a wall-safe, what would be the most efficient way to do that?

When I added a vent to the bathroom I simply drilled a lot of holes next to each other in a circular shape with a long drill-bit. That and a hammer and I was done.

But for the size of a wall-safe, that will take me many man-years to do.

What tools or techniques do I need?

<sup>I do not want outsiders to install the safe; security by obscurity is a safety feature I hope to gain.</sup>

Comment: Make sure this wall is not load-bearing and not structural.

Comment: @KromstersayssupportMonica - good point. "Those" walls are reinforced and way too thick to even contemplate drilling into them.

Comment: The reasoning is that if they were made strong enough - that was made for some reason. Better check on that before it all goes cracking and collapses when you remove significant portion of it's body (and rebar reinforcements that are inside).

Comment: Please add wall specifications and  details, as well as safe dimensions to the question.

Comment: How about adding a 'fake' 2x4 stud wall a foot from the concrete wall?

Answer (score 2):

The *simplest and most efficient* method is to add a new wall, and have the safe in place when you pour it.

Barring that, for a "really, I'm QUITE sure it's not structural" wall, rental or purchase of various destructive technologies will aid the process - diamond core drills can make large holes cleanly and quickly. Diamond saw blades can make grooves between holes (few will make it through the entire wall thickness, and those would be hard to manage anyway) or for a cruder approach various levels of jackhammer-related tooling (hammer-drills at the low end, actual jackhammers that are a bit much to manage on a wall at the high end) will bash out concrete and/or drill holes somewhat faster than regular drills but more crudely than core drills. Presumably you'll pour new concrete (or grout) around the safe when in place, so crude may not matter much, so long as you don't knock the whole wall down.

Comment: I like the idea of pouring a new concrete wall around the safe. You could tie the new wall to the existing wall with steel anchors and rebar anchored to the existing wall. (Make sure the floor can support all the added weight, including what is going in the safe.)

Comment: Unfortunately, building a wall is not one of the practical options that I have. :-(